# How does CSS inherit behave?

Tags: css, inheritance

I have seen an example in [MDN lesson](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) about inheritance, and I can't understand why the third link's color is black?  it should be blue, like a usual link, because the initial value supposes to be the default value!

Thank you for helping me.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  color: green;
}

.my-class-1 a {
  color: inherit;
}

.my-class-2 a {
  color: initial;
}

.my-class-3 a {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because the initial color of  attrubutes are black, same with

here is an example from w3schools where they set the color of the division to red, but using initial resets h1 to the base color of  attributes.

```css
div {
    color: red;
}

#initialH1Color {
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1 id="initialH1Color">this will be initial color</h1>
<h1>this will be div color: red</h1>
</div>
```

---

### here is an example of inherit

---

```css
div{
  background: #333;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  color: lime;
}

.initial {
  color: initial;
}

.inherit {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="initial">class initial</h1>
  <h1 class="inherit">class inherit</h1>
  <h1>no class</h1>
</div>
```

as you can see here class inherit and no class are the same color, that is because inherit is the automatic/normal/basic/initial value for color

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its parent element.

### UPDATE

the reason for the a attribute beeing blue by default (which it is not, it is black). is because it is a link. take a look at the example

```html
<a>no href tag = black</a>
<a href="#">has href tag = blue</a>
<a href="#" >same with this one</a>
```

Comment: So, what gives to an a element the blue color by default?

Comment: @JonatanBar-Hen that is a great question, i have updated my answer